# Partial Background images repeat in IE?

Tags: html, css

In my site, there are divs with repeated bg images. It renders smoothly in FF. But gets jagged in IE while scrolling the page.
This is the image shot of the site:
[alt text http://img44.imageshack.us/img44/2851/beforescroll.png](http://img44.imageshack.us/img44/2851/beforescroll.png)

As you can see the image is self descriptive, the bg is not repeated smoothly.
Now, when I scroll the page, the bg image is not shown at all. This is the shot of the site after scrolling.
[alt text http://img196.imageshack.us/img196/7184/afterscroll.png](http://img196.imageshack.us/img196/7184/afterscroll.png)

What might be the problem with this ie thing?

Answer (score 0):

If you have floating content inside the divs the parent div is not properly cleared. Add overflow:hidden; clear:both; to the div with the bg